# Need to build a Python/Django "dashboard" to replace system emails to admins

Tags: python, django, dashboard

For my python/django site I need to build a "dashboard" that will update me on the status of dozens of error/heartbeat/unexpected events going on.

There are a few types of "events" that I'm currently tracking by having the Django site send emails to the admin accounts:

1) Something that normally should happen goes wrong.  We synch files to different services and other machines every few hours and I send error emails when this goes wrong.

2) When something that should happen actually happens.  Sometimes events in item #1 fail so horribly that they don't even send emails (try: except: around an event should always work, but things can get deleted from the crontab, the system configuration can get knocked askew where things won't run, etc. where I won't even get an error email and the lack of a success/heartbeat email will let me know something that should have happened didn't happen.)

3) When anything unexpected happens.  We've made a lot of assumptions on how backend operations will run and if any of these assumptions are violated (e.g. we find two users who have the same email address) we want to know about it.  These events aren't necessarily errors, more like warnings to investigate.

So I want to build a dashboard that I can easily update from python/django to give me a bird's eye view of all of these types of activity so I can stop sending hundreds of emails out per week (which is already unmanageble.)

Comment: Opened link to question to find a question, left disappointed.

Comment: Are you the one receiving the e-mails or sending them to someone else?

Comment: "So I want to build a dashboard".  Cool.  Any problems?  Any questions?  Any difficulties?  Any roadblocks?  Any impediments?  Or are you using StackOverflow as your "to do" list?

Comment: This negative voting and closing is BS.  This is a problem tons of people have had (or will have when their application grows) and I can't be the first person to encounter it and try to solve it.  I shouldn't have to write the whole solution myself before reaching out to the StackOverflow community for help.  There are hundreds of people who have solved this same problem on their own who haven't yet open sourced it or written about it who stackoverflow.com could help connect together and compile that data for the public to view.

Comment: @MikeN: "reaching out to the StackOverflow community for help".  Help with what?  There's no question.  Just a statement.  How can we help?  What' do you want to do that you can't do?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to create a basic logging system that outputs to a web page.

So you could write something simple app called, say, `systemevents` that creates an `Event` record each time something happens on the site. You'd add a signal hook so that anywhere in the rest of the site you could code something like:

```
from systemevents.signals import record_event

...

try:
    # code goes here
except Exception, inst:
    record_event("Error occurred while taunting %s: %s" % (obj, inst,), type="Error")
else:
    record_event("Successfully taunted %s" % (obj, ), type="Success")
```

Then you can pretty easily create a view that lists these events.

However, keep in mind that this is adding a layer of complexity that is highly problematic. What if the error lies in your database? Then each time you try to record an error event, another error occurs!

Far better to use something like a built-in logging system to create a text-based log file, then whip up something that can import that text file and lay it out in a somewhat more readable fashion.

One more tip: in order to change how Django handles exceptions, you have to write a [custom view for 500 errors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view). If using `systemevents`, you'd write something like:

```
from django.views.defaults import server_error
def custom_error_view(request)
    try:
        import sys
        type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()    
        error_message = "" # create an error message from the values above
        record_event("Error occurred: %s" % (error_message,), type="Error")
    except Exception:
        pass
    return server_error(request)
```

Note that none of this code has been tested for correctness. It's just meant as a guide.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at django-sentry?
http://dcramer.github.com/django-sentry/